# Change layout of "My Orders" page

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm customizing the `customer_account` section of my store and would like to two different layouts for the pages in this section.

I was able to customize the whole `customer_account` section to use the `customer-account.phtml` like this (in `THEME_NAME/default/layout/customer.xml`):

```
<customer_account translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account (All Pages)</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/customer-account.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addBodyClass"><class>customer-account</class></action>
    </reference>
    ...
</customer_account>
```

I've tried adding the following to the `customer_account` but it's not working:

```
    <reference name="orders">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

How can I use a different layout for the "My Orders" section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on my order you can see url `sales/order/history`

That means its not use customer_account layout directly But for My orders You can find this code in `sales.xml` file

```
<sales_order_history translate="label">
        <label>Customer My Account Order History</label>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="sales/order_history" name="sales.order.history">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="sales.order.history.info" as="info" translate="label">
                    <label>Order History Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer.account.link.back" template="customer/account/link/back.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </sales_order_history>
```

So you need to define template here

```
<reference name="root">
              <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

Hope this will help.